# Read/Write data from/to Excel using multiple threads/processes in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, selenium, csv

I'm working on a project which requires filling up a form (reading the input data from an excel sheet) and getting an output value (and save it to the excel sheet) when hitting the submit button. I have managed to automate this process with Python+Selenium but it takes quite some time to go over all rows of the xls file.

*Note: `XLUtils` is another python file with helper functions. I'm also using `openpyxl` and `xlrd` to read/write from the excel file*

**Here's the code (NO THREADS) on a high level:**

```
#Initial set-up
url = "https://url.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

#Location of the input sheet
path = "C:/Book1.xlsx"

#Get number of rows from the excel input sheet
rows = XLUtils.getRowCount()

#Log into website
XLUtils.login(driver)

#Loop through all records from the input sheet
for row_num in range(4, rows + 1):
    try:
        XLUtils.fill_out_form(driver, path, row_num)
    except:
        print("Element not found and test failed")
        continue

#Log out and close Browser
XLUtils.logout(driver)
```

**Here's an example of threading but it's quite simple as you would see below:**

```
def test_logic():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']").send_keys("python threading")
    time.sleep(1)
    # driver.quit()

num_browsers = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
thread_list = list()

# Start test
for i in range(num_browsers):
    t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started!')
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('Test completed!')
```

**My question is**: How can I merge the two codes to achieve my goal? Is it just a matter of wrapping the process I want to replicate in a function and then passing this function to the Threading code piece? If so, how would I manage to loop the entire xls file in batches of 5 and read/write each one from/to the resulting excel file.

It's a tricky problem and I honestly haven't found a similar question around this so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  

  import XL_utility # Importing from my second file
  from selenium import webdriver
  import unittest
  import time
  
  
  class Test_Excel(unittest.TestCase):
  
      def setUp(self):
                           
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
          self.driver.get("https://eu-uat2-int.weissr-cloud.com/auth")
          self.driver.maximize_window()
  
          return self.driver
  
      def test_read_excel_file(self):
  
          path = "...location..."
          print(path.title())
  
          rows = XL_utility.getRowCount(path, "Sheet1")
  
          for r in range(2, rows + 1):
              username = XL_utility.readData(path, "Sheet1", r, 1)
              password = XL_utility.readData(path, "Sheet1", r, 2)
  
              self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
              self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
  
              self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("auth- 
              form__submit").click()
  
              time.sleep(10)
  
  
              if self.driver.title == "Weissr":
                  print("Test is passed!")
                  XL_utility.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Test passed")
              else:
                  print("Test failed")
                  XL_utility.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Test failed")
  
              self.driver.back()
              return self.driver
  
  
  
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  
  # The following code is from the second file...
  
  
  import openpyxl
  
  
  def getRowCount(file, sheetName):
      workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
      sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
      return sheet.max_row
  
  
  def getColumnCount(file, sheetName):
      workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
      sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
      return sheet.max_column
  
  
  def readData(file, sheetName, rownum, columnno):
      workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
      sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
      return sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columnno).value
  
  
  def writeData(file, sheetName, rownum, columnno, data):
      workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
      sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
      sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columnno).value = data
      workbook.save(file)
```

Comment: You should enhance the quality of your answer by determining what problems are being addressed by the code you provided. Right now, you are just hoping that an unknown number of problems would be fixed. Moreover, adding documentation to your code can definitely improve the answer and its chance to get upvoted by community.